# What software exists for bridging a 64-bit ODBC app to a 32-bit ODBC driver on windows?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, odbc

The problem I am looking to solve is communicating from a 64-bit app through ODBC with a datasource for which there only exists a 32-bit ODBC-driver. One solution that would suffice for the moment is using an ODBC-to-ODBC bridge.

I found an ODBC-to-ODBC bridging-software created by Easysoft. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out www.datadirect.com

Answer (score 2):

Simba has an ODBC to ODBC bridge as part of our SimbaEngine ODBC SDK.  You can get a free evaluation version of it at http://www.simba.com/evaluate-odbc-sdk.htm.  When you fill out the form, explain that you want to bridge from a 64-bit ODBC app to a 32-bit ODBC driver.